# Cannot enable form elements

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I made a random number generator in HTML, and it gives the user to generate any random number or a random number between a user-specified range. When the page loads, the elements are disabled and the user needs to select which generator they want to use via radio buttons. If the user selects the option to generate any number, the generate button gets enabled and the specific generator elements stay disabled (and vice-versa).

I've managed to get the elements to be disabled when the page loads, but when the radio buttons are selected, the elements remain disabled. How can I get the respective elements to enable and disable accordingly.

```html
<script>
  document.getElementById('btnAny').disabled = true;
  document.getElementById('txtMin').disabled = true;
  document.getElementById('txtMax').disabled = true;
  document.getElementById('btnSpecific').disabled = true;

  function checked() {
    if (document.getElementById('radioAny').checked == true) {
      document.getElementById('btnAny').disabled = false;
    } else if (document.getElementById('radioSpecific').checked == true) {
      document.getElementById('txtMin').disabled = false;
      document.getElementById('txtMax').disabled = false;
      document.getElementById('btnSpecific').disabled = false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

The `check()` function is run in the radio buttons as follows (`onchange` had no effect either):

```
<input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radioAny" onclick="checked()">Any Number
```

Comment: When is `checked` ran?

Comment: Add an onchange event handler to the radio button that will trigger the checked function. You can also just add the `disabled` attribute to the HTML elements that have to start off disabled instead of using javascript to disable them on page load.

Comment: @tymeJV I've added that to the question details

Comment: @Shilly I tried onchange and it didn't help. I read that using the disabled attribute in the HTML element itself will not allow it to become enabled later on when needed.

Comment: Verify the function is actually running (use a log statement, check your console), verify you actually have elements with those IDs on the page.

Comment: @tymeJV I'm using notepad++ so I don't know if I can pull any logs. But I did run through the code line by line and made sure that I was referencing the correct IDs.

Comment: @RedCode Do you have an example of the onchange handler you tried? And concerning the disabled attribute, what you read is wrong. `<button disabled>Click Me</button><script>document.querySelector( 'button' ).disabled = false;</script>` works perfectly.

Comment: @RedCode - Your IDE has nothing to do with logs. In your browser, open the console (usually F12 does this) - this is where you view the output of `console.logs` and any JavaScript errors. Not that I don't trust you, but I believe the console more than the line by line analysis :)

Comment: @Shilly I just tried your suggestion now and still not working.

Comment: @tymeJV Okay I had a look and this is what it says: `Uncaught TypeError: checked is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (RandomNumberGen.html:18)`

Comment: Place your `script` tags at the end of your `body` content.

Comment: @tymeJV My script is already at the end of my body content. But I've managed to resolve the issue and posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've managed to get this working and I think I know why. What I failed to take into account is that `checked` may be a reserved word for a built in function for radio buttons.

For example seeing if a radio button is checked:

```
if(document.getElementById('radioAny').checked == true)
```

So I think this was causing a conflict when I named my function `checked()`. I changed my function name to `checkedd()`, kept all my initial code, changed the onclick call for the radio buttons accordingly and it works perfectly fine now.